# For each Raw in a an excel call shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xlsx

xlsx with some rows like

```
OP20
MA20
```

for each row in the excel, I need to call a shell script  as an argument

```
while read p; do
 ./command.sh $p
done <Name.xlsx
```

I have code like this but after running the code I get some junk character as output.

Comment: To clarify: you need this on a Unix system, where you can't run Excel?

Comment: in unix we can not read excel ?I do not want to run excel I just need to read excel

Comment: .xlsx is a zipped XML format. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: You will need to run something like xls2csv first.

Comment: it is ok instead of excel if I have csv..But will the above code work if it is a csv ?

Comment: @VishnuSajeevan Yes, you could use ASCII CSV files

Comment: Or regarding your post: as suggested by @RamanSailopal, something like: `xls2csv Name.xlsx | xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 ./command.sh`

Comment: I modified command like this while read p; do
 ./command.sh $p
done <Name.xlsx  but it is reading the newline character also

Comment: @VishnuSajeevan : Each iteration in your loop reads from the input file the characters until the respective next line feed, splits this string on white space characters, and passes these split-up parts as a set of parameters to `command.sh`. You can access the individual pieces as parameters $1, $2, ....

Comment: it is a valid question, I am not asking for software recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### XLS files in bash

You have to convert your .xls file in ASCII:

```
xls2csv Name.xlsx | xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 ./command.sh
```

Than `xargs` will run `./command.sh` once by line, successively, with each line as arguments.

#### `xml2csv` alternative:

You could use [libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) command line for this:

```
soffice --convert-to "csv" Name.xlsx
xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 ./command.sh <Name.csv
```

#### `libreoffice` based solution using *tab* instead of *coma*:

```
soffice --convert-to 'csv:Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):9,34,UTF8' --headless file.xlsx
while IFS=$'\t' read -aru ${tsv} array;do
    echo "Line: $array"   # show first field
    declare -p array
done {tsv}<file.csv
```

Comment: bash: xls2csv: command not found... I am getting so I changed  Name.xlsx to Name.csv and trying to run ./command.sh for each line in Name.csv, Can you please help me with the command

Comment: @VishnuSajeevan You may have to install `xml2csc` or use other alternatives... Answer edited!

Comment: @F.Hauri..It is working but it is taking the newline character also as argument ,/command.sh OP20 it is invoking ./command.sh OP20 and a newline character

Comment: You could drop leading *newline* by using `${variable%$'\n'}` in `command.sh`.

Comment: @VishnuSajeevan This strange: I just tested: `xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 ./command.sh <Name.csv`, There is no leading newlines! Wich OS / Environment are you using?